# Internal User Versus External User Versus anonymous user in SharePoint 2013

Tags: .net, licensing

I have read the new police for SharePoint licensing price, and it mentioned that no extra license price will be needed for any external web sites. But I have the following questions to know exactly the budget I need to buy SharePoint 2013:-

1. Regarding the number of Internal Users:-

   ```
        Q1.a Are we talking about named users or concurrent users.

        Q1.b If the internal system is published to the web, (for example the system allow the company employees to manage their documents from home). Then will all the internal users still be considered internal? Or in this was they will be considered as external users?.

        Q1.c in our case we have 55 employees which will be dealing with SharePoint, then I should buy 55 license (which will cost 109$ per user)?
   ```
2. Regarding the number of external users:-

   ```
       Q2.a Are we talking about named users or concurrent users.

       Q2.b if I create an information web site using SharePoint , which allows anonymous users to access the system; then if my website is visited by 5,000 users or by 10,000 users  does this have to do with the license price?.

       Q2.c if my external system allows online registration, then how i can manage that only approved users will consume a valid license.

       Q2.d if each customer have number of users who will be interested to access the external site , the should I send them only one license user or I should create users equal to the number of customer’s employees who will be accessing the SharePoint?
   ```
3. Currently we have 55 internal users, 85 customers :- then I made the following estimation for SP 2013

$6,798.00 .To purchase SP

55 * 109 = $6,000 .For internal users.

External users I cannot determine, sine I still have the following pending issues:-

```
    Q3.a Should I send each customer one license user

    Q3.b or I should create users equal to the customer’s employees interested to access the SharePoint 

    Q3c and what about anonymous users
```

Sorry for the long email & thanks for any help.

Best Regards

Comment: thanks for your reply , i am just trying to find approximate prices before contacting Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

This article may help explain their new pricing: http://www.degdigital.com/blog/big-changes-in-sharepoint-2013-licensing-for-portal-clients/

But personally I would talk with Microsoft as it doesn't cost anything to make the call and they may be able to make deals for your situation.

Comment: i tried to contact them but i did not get any reply till now.

Comment: If they had anything helpful to say you should add it as an answer for future users.

Comment: I have a question - Do you have a windows Server to run Sharepoint ? OR u looking for sharepoint online ?